# JSON_EXTRACT as VALUES for INSERT INTO?

Tags: mysql, json, syntax

I expect the following MySQL code:

```
SET @json= '{"1":{"name":"Name","value":"James Bowery","id":1,"type":"name","first":"James","middle":"","last":"Bowery"},"2":{"name":"Birthdate","value":"06\/23\/2017","id":2,"type":"date-time","date":"06\/23\/2017","time":"","unix":1498176000},"3":{"name":"Gender","value":"Male","value_raw":"Male","id":3,"type":"radio"},"4":{"name":"Ethnicity","value":"European","value_raw":"European","id":4,"type":"radio"},"5":{"name":"Email","value":"jabowery@emailservice.com","id":5,"type":"text"}}';
SET @array = JSON_EXTRACT( @json, '$."1".first','$."1".last','$."5".value','$."2".value','$."3".value','$."4".value');
INSERT INTO user (firstname,lastname,birthdate,gender,ethnicity,email) VALUES (@array);
```

To insert a row into the `user` table populated by the named fields extracted from the JSON.  However, the `INSERT` yields a syntax error.  What is the proper syntax?

Comment: whether `@array` has expected value ?

Comment: `@array` has the value `["James", "Bowery", "06/23/2017", "Male", "European", "jabowery@emailservice.com"]`if that answers your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perhaps try this.  Note that I have changed the date format to yyyy-MM-dd.  You will need to work on converting this programatically to fit to MySQL.  Also, when I ran this, the array had email before birthdate, so I changed the sequence of insert.

```
 SET @json= '{"1":{"name":"Name","value":"James Bowery","id":1,"type":"name","first":"James","middle":"","last":"Bowery"},"2":{"name":"Birthdate","value":"06\/23\/2017","id":2,"type":"date-time","date":"2017-06-23","time":"","unix":1498176000},"3":{"name":"Gender","value":"Male","value_raw":"Male","id":3,"type":"radio"},"4":{"name":"Ethnicity","value":"European","value_raw":"European","id":4,"type":"radio"},"5":{"name":"Email","value":"jabowery@emailservice.com","id":5,"type":"text"}}';
SET @array = JSON_EXTRACT( @json, '$."1".first','$."1".last','$."5".value','$."2".value','$."3".value','$."4".value');
SET @queryString=   CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO user (firstname,lastname,email,birthdate,gender,ethnicity) VALUES (',REPLACE(REPLACE(@array, '[',''),']',''),')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '["James", "Bowery", "06/23/2017", "Male", "European", "jabowery@emailservice.com' at line 1`

Comment: I'll accept that, although I ended up doing a `JSON_EXTRACT` for each of the fields because each of them required different string manipulations and function calls.  For instance, the date conversion, etc.  I find it rather strange that `JSON_EXTRACT` produces JSON rather than genuinely extracting the values into SQL space.

Comment: This could've been done differently, without a prepared statement.